# React Native Axios get response Skipped and Status Code 0

Tags: react-native, http, https, axios

I got a problem with my react native app. while accessing API, I get a response Skipped and status code 0. it's shown by using reactotron to log the api response, but when I `console.log` the error, it just only says:

> "Error: Network Error".

It happens with HTTP and HTTPS. But it depends on my network too. When I use cellular data and my home WiFi, it's able to access the API, but when I use my office WiFi, sometimes it gives the error and sometimes it's success to be accessed. I don't know where's the problem, is it from react native configuration or the Back End (REST API).

This is the screenshot of reactotron log:

[image]

and this is the screenshot of `console.log(error)`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same error, but it was just the emulator date that was way behind the current day. I don't know for sure the cause of the problem, but when leaving the date as automatic solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error many times. one of the sources is `SSL handshake failure` which is likely to happen due to poor connections.

If You are getting this error on all networks (cellular and wifi), and You are pretty sure Your connection is OK, then I suggest to locate the issue at server side (SSL config for example).